# How do Linear regression - predict more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I need to change the following method to calculate and return the linear regression prediction
(for either the multivariate or the univariate case).

Note: the 'predict' method should be used both for the predictions on the test-set,
as well as during the training process.

**input parameters:**

- x_feature_vectors - a dataframe containing all feature vectors for which we want to predict the y_predicted values,
  using the linear regression model's weights.

  Note: it is expected the the x_feature_vectors contain a fictive column of features, with
  the constant value of 1, representing the x_0 fictive feature (called 'x_0').
- trained_w - the trained w-vector, i.e. the trained weight vector (or the weight vector from some step in the training).

  Note: it is expected the the trained_w series contain, the w_0 cell as a first cell.
  The index of all cells are expected to fit the 'columns' (i.e. column titles which
  are the column indexes) of the 'x_feature_vectors' dataframe, including the 'x_0'
  fictive column.

**return value:**

- y_predicted - a series of the predictions for each input feature vector instance

My code :

```py
def predict(x_featureVectors,trained_w):
    
    y_predicted = pd.Series(index=x_featureVectors.index, dtype=float)
    
    for index in x_featureVectors.index:
        y_predicted[index] = 0
        for col in x_featureVectors.columns:
            y_predicted[index] += trained_w[col] * x_featureVectors.loc[index, col]
    
    return y_predicted
```

How can I do this more efficient ? Can I do this with one for loop ?

Comment: Can you please provide a full rannuable example, including input and output data? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a fictive column, the prediction is just vector of dot products of each row with weight vector:

```
def predict(x_featureVectors, trained_w):
    return np.dot(x_featureVectors, trained_w)
```